# Generate different random numbers

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate different random numbers . I used srand and rand , but in my output some numbers are identical .

This is my output :
[image]

How to do with srand to generate different numbers ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    time_t t;
std::vector<int> myVector;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){

    int b = rand() % 100;
    myVector.push_back(b);
    std::cout << myVector[i] << std::endl;
}
Sleep(50000);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean it generates the same random sequence every time it's executed?

Comment: Random numbers still include _identical_ numbers, there's no guarantee the random generator engine generates unique numbers.

Comment: You could push the results to an array, then remove duplicates

Comment: And how can I do to generate unique numbers?

Comment: If you want unique random numbers you'll need to either remove duplicates after generation as @Timothy Kanski suggested or use something like `std::find` to check if the container already contains the generated number during the loop; or use a different container such as `std::set` to avoid equivalent values occurring.

Comment: Search SO for "[c++] unique random" there are lots of answers that deal with this.

Comment: As an aside, if you need high quality random numbers then avoid using `rand()` (and especially avoid `rand() % 100`) and instead use an engine from the `<random>` header (e.g. `std::mt19937`) if c++11 is available to you

Comment: Interestingly, having identical numbers doesn't mean that your output is not random.

Comment: Better answer than any given here: [Sampling without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922917/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-use-random-number-deduplication)

Answer (score 7):

One easy way is to add all numbers from 0-99 to a vector and shuffle it, then you can get as many (up to 100) non repeating random numbers as you require.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {

    std::vector<int> numbers;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)       // add 0-99 to the vector
        numbers.push_back(i);

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    for(int i=0; i<40; i++)        // print the first 40 randomly sorted numbers
        std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Instead of the loop adding the numbers to the vector, one could set its size correctly to begin with, and then use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: An explanation to your answer? How does this guarantee non-identical numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a set:

```
std::set<int> numbers;
while (numbers.size() < 40)
{
    numbers.add(rand() % 100);
}
```

and then copy it into a `vector` if necessary.

Comment: + Shuffle the values after copying them to vector, or they'll be sorted.

Comment: @Roux or use an `std::unordered_set` if c++ 11 is available

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the idea of using `set` is not so good, because the generating time of every new value increases. If you have enough memory it seems that usage of an array can be preferable.

In the next code, I don't use shuffle, instead, I use a random function just `size` times to choose one value. I add it to the destination vector, then in the source array, swap the value with the last element and decrease `arr_size`.

```
/*
 * Return random unsigned int value using intrinsic
 * */
unsigned getRandom() {
    unsigned val;
    _rdrand32_step(&val);
    return val;
}

/*
 * Return a vector<int> of uniq numbers in a range of [min ... max).
 *
 * @param min - min value.
 * @param max - max value.
 * @param size - amount of uniq numbers (size <= max-min).
 * */
vector<int> getUniqNumbers(int min, int max, unsigned size) {
    int arr_size = max - min;
    int *a = new int[arr_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        a[i] = min + i;
    }

    vector<int> numbers(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned u_rand = getRandom() % arr_size;
        numbers[i] = a[u_rand];
        a[u_rand] = a[--arr_size];
    }
    delete[] a;
    return numbers;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

srand number generator can give  identical numbers.

You could implement a solution which deletes duplicates not adding them to the vector. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    while(myVector.size() < 40)
    {
        int b = rand() % 100;
        if ( !(std::find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), b) != myVector.end()))
        {
           myVector.push_back(b);
           std::cout << myVector.at(myVector.size()-1) << std::endl;
        }

    }
    Sleep(50000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of getting rid of duplicates is using `std::unique` in `<algorithm>`.

Here is an example of that in use:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int ran(int min, int max)
{
    std::random_device r;
    std::mt19937 gen(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(min, max);
    return dis(gen);
}

int main()
{
    const int fill_size = 10; 
    const int min = 1;        // min random number
    const int max = 100;      // max random number

    std::vector<int> vec;
    while (vec.size() != fill_size) {
        vec.emplace_back(ran(min, max)); // create new random number
        std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec)); // sort before call to unique
        auto last = std::unique(begin(vec), end(vec));
        vec.erase(last, end(vec));       // erase duplicates
    }

    std::random_shuffle(begin(vec), end(vec)); // mix up the sequence
    for (const auto& i : vec)                  // and display elements
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve a unique set of random numbers writing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        int b = rand() % 100;
        if(!std::find(std::begin(myvector),std::end(myvector),b)) {
            myVector.push_back(b);
            std::cout << myVector[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a statistical (mathematical) issue. Random numbers may be identical to eachother. If you need unique numbers, you must check to see if they are used before. For example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){

    int b = rand() % 100;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(myVector[j]==b)i--;
        else{
            myVector.push_back(b);
            std::cout << myVector[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```