# Is there an efficient way to use random number deduplication?

Tags: c++, random

I making a program that uses random numbers.
I wrote the code as below, but the number of loops was higher than I expected
Is there an efficient way to use random number deduplication?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define MAX 1000
int main(void)
{
    int c[MAX] = {};
    int i, j = 0;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        c[i] = rand() % 10000;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (c[i] == c[j])
            {
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First I recommend you learn more about [the C++ standard random number generation library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Then I suggest you use a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to get unique values.

Comment: What do  you mean by random number deduplication?

Comment: @eerorika; the algo suggests that OP wants 1000 *distinct* random integers in the [0, 1000) range

Comment: Shuffle algorithms as [Fisher-Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) might help.

Comment: place 1 to `MAX` elements into array and then [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: @SergeBallesta the range is [0, 10000), not [0, 1000)

Comment: OP wants a [*sample*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) of 1000 numbers from the range [0, 10000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is [sampling without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample). [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) does exactly that, you just need to supply it with your population of numbers.

[`std::ranges::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) can be your population without having to store 10000 numbers.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> c(1000);
    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}()); // or a better initialisation
    auto numbers = std::ranges::views::iota(0, 9999);
    std::sample(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), c.begin(), 1000, gen);

    for (int i : c) 
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fcc6c9eb9aeba5c)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Populate the `vector` with increasing numbers till `MAX` and then shuffle it.

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
#define MAX 1000

int main()
{  
    std::vector<int> v(MAX) ; // vector with 1000 ints.
    std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
 
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/JxTAcCEx3)

Comment: shuffle is the correct solution, however the way you're generating isn't what the OP wants, because they need 1000 values in the range [0, 10000) so some changes need to be done to the generator

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that avoids initializing an array with the size of max like the answer of TruthSeeker, so it takes less memory. It has uniform sampling.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> random_set(int count, int maximum_value)
{
    assert(count <= maximum_value + 1);

    std::vector<int> output;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> jump;

    auto helper_maximum = maximum_value;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i, --helper_maximum)
    {
        const auto selector_origin = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, helper_maximum)(gen);
        auto selector = selector_origin;

        while (true)
        {
            auto it = jump.find(selector); 
            if (it == jump.end()) break;
            selector = it->second;
        }

        jump[selector_origin] = helper_maximum;
        output.push_back(selector);
    }

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    random_set(10, 15000);
}
```